# using watch , tail and ccze together

Tags: linux, bash, shell, monitoring

I have used watch and tail together like this:

```
watch -n 5 tail -n 15 mylogfile.txt
```

Also I have used tail and ccze for colorizing log file as below:

```
tail -f -n 50 mylogfile.txt | ccze
```

But I dont know how should I use all of these three together in a single command. Does any one have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recent versions of watch has `-c | --color` option, so perhaps this will work for you:

```
watch -n 5 -c 'tail -f -n 50 mylogfile.txt | ccze'
```