# Corrupted log is generated when using watch , tail and ccze command through putty

Tags: bash, shell, colors, monitoring, putty

I use putty to connnect to a cubietruck board which has armbian debian jessie software on it. I want to see coloured live log of an app. I followed the following example [using watch , tail and ccze together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670204/using-watch-tail-and-ccze-together).
When I use the command :

```
 tail -f app.log | ccze
```

It worked great. Also when I use the command :

```
watch  `tail -f  app.log`
```

It also worked great. However  when I gave :

```
watch --color 'tail -f  app.log | ccze'
```

or

```
 watch -c 'tail -f  app.log | ccze'
```

I get a lot of

> (B

charachter and in the text  in most of the cases no new lines are recognized and looks as seamless text. I assume that the color related ASCII characters are not decoded correctly.
I also changed the putty keyboard from ESC to VT400 and Linux but the same problem occured.
Does anyone has an idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For better understanding: why do you explicitly want to use `watch`? if you want to be informed about recent changes of app.log, then `tail -f app.log | ccze` should do it.

Comment: @Rene Knop I tried this approach but when I wanted to slow down the log with the s (sleep) argument the log speed didn't changed whatever value I inserted.
tail -f -s 5 app.log | ccze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
watch -c -n5 'tail app.log | ccze -A'
```

- Leaving out the `-f` parameter for `tail`, to stop tail watching for changes in the log file (because `watch` should do that)
- Adding the `-A` parameter to `ccze` to enable raw ANSI colors